# Cannot access a control which is in the repeater , from the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

i am trying access an asp label within an asp repeater from my code behind file. here is what i have done so far :

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="outerFunction">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <h1>Questions And Answers</h1>
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
             <p style="background-color:Red; color:Yellow;"><%#Eval("QText") %> :::::::::</p>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# setQID(Eval("QID"))%>' />

            <asp:Label ID="pageLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

             <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2">
                 <HeaderTemplate>

                 </HeaderTemplate>
                 <ItemTemplate>



                    <%# (GetAnswer(Eval("AnsQID"))) != 1 ? (displayAnswer(Eval("AText"))) : ""%>


                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>

                </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>

            <span style="display:block; border-top:1px solid Gray;"></span>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

**Here is my code behind **

```
public void outerFunction(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs  e)
    {
       Label myLabel =  (Label) e.Item.FindControl("pageLabel");
       myLabel.Text = "HELLO World";
    }
```

I am trying to display Questions and Answers. For every question there can be multiple answers. That is why i have it in a nested repeater control. For now I just need to know how i can have say for example have a "div" element in the outer repeater and bind every answer i get within the inner repeater to that parent div.

Thanks !

Comment: It's just an advice but in my opinion it is easier for code readability to name your event handlers <Control>_<Event>: `Repeater1_ItemDataBound`. Reading the name then says it all.

Comment: thanks ! i will keep that in mind next time !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code looks good except that you are not checking the type of row you are in:

```
public void outerFunction(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs  e)
 {
      if(e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
      {
         Label myLabel =  (Label) e.Item.FindControl("pageLabel");
         myLabel.Text = "HELLO World";
      }
 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! this does the job ! does this work for generic html controls too ?

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz: Yes, it does as long as you put `runat="server"` on the generic control markup.

Comment: Thanks! In my case the method was the OnItemDataBound of the repeater.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a header template that does not contain a "pageLabel", you'll get a null reference error when that portion of the repeater is data bound.

Put the label portion in an if block:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
{
...
}
```

If you use the AlternatingItemTemplate, you'll also want to include that:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you are doing right now is not safe when the currently processed item is the header or footer, label is in `ItemTemplate` so will be available only for the DataItems, try like this:

```
public void outerFunction(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs  e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Label myLabel =  (Label) e.Item.FindControl("pageLabel");
        myLabel.Text = "HELLO World";
    }
}
```